# NVidia rtx with OptiX doesn’t seem much faster than CUDA. Is this right?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have windows 10 64 bit, and an NVidia GeForce RTX 2060 super. GPU compute is successfully enabled for the graphics card, and is unchecked from using my CPU graphics. I have tried both CUDA and OptiX on the same scene in Cycles, and while CUDA Has a render time of 6 minutes and 56 seconds, OptiX does 5 minutes and 37 seconds. That is about 1/5 of the time cut off, but with RTX, shouldn’t OptiX be MUCH faster, or is this the norm? My drivers are (or were) up to date, and I have blender 2.93. The same was true of 2.92, though.

Comment: Can you share the `.blend` file and we'll test it out? if confidential IP we can try using a demo blend

Comment: @Lowlande52 Will work on doing so…

Comment: @Lowlande52 do you mind if it’s on OneDrive instead of blend exchange? It’s not very big, but that might be easier for me at the moment.

Comment: @Lowlande52 Here is the file. I’m sorry it’s not on blend-exchange. Technical difficulties https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgH_S_5HSwNXhnB3J_apu3oEDASc

Comment: From my experience Optix has been at times even slower than CUDA